# Can I watch Naruto Shippuden movies anytime?

Tags: naruto

I barely started watching anime, and *Naruto* was the first anime I watched. I'm currently in the middle of *Naruto Shippuden* (episode 71).

Before I go on, do I have to watch any of the movies, or can I watch them anytime? If it's necessary, what's the order to watch the movies?

Answer (score 4):

[u/IdRatherBeLurking's comment on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/2sdm2z/what_order_do_the_movies_go_in_with_respect_to/?st=J3DKCD6O&sh=f7c44a81) shows the episode number that you should have watched up to before-hand. That's if you don't want any spoilers. Quoted below;

> **Part 1**
>
> 1. Clash in the Land of Snow - after episode 101
> 2. Legend of the Stone of Gelel - after episode 160
> 3. Guardians of the Crescent Moon Kingdom - after episode 196
>
> **Shippūden**
>
> Some of these films don't directly follow an episode, so I've deduced
>   where they are in chronological order based on release date.
>
> 4. Naruto Shippūden the Movie - after episode ~23
> 5. Bonds - after episode ~70
> 6. The Will of Fire - after episode ~121
> 7. The Lost Tower - after episode 169
> 8. Blood Prison - after episode ~221
> 9. Road to Ninja: Naruto the Movie - after episode 271
> 10. The Last - Naruto the Movie - between chapters 699 and 700 of the manga

[Sahan De Silva's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/40599/can-i-watch-the-naruto-shippuden-movies-anytime#comment54972_40599) is right by saying that it won't confuse you regarding the storyline as they are their own short stories.